# Renaming image file names

Tags: seo, filesystem

I have a client that would like to edit file names for photos that site members have uploaded. She wants to rename them for SEO purposes. (e.g. changing name from DSC_00234.jpg to a-descriptive-title.jpg)

Here is a bit more detail:

- Members each have an account where they can create a profile about their services/products and they can upload multiple photos
- The photos are stored in a Matrix with image input and descriptive caption (which is used in alt text)
- We are concerned with making sure that when an image is renamed it will still be linked properly in the entry in the Matrix field

Other Notes:

- Client would prefer to be able to edit these filenames herself *after* they have been uploaded, rather then *at the time of upload* by site members, so that she has more control.
- A solution that would automatically rename them to something useful (rather than having client edit them herself) would work for us too.
- We did not see anything that would do this with either built-in EE functionality or with add-ons. (Thought it's possible we might have missed an add-on.)

Any recommendations on a decent way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters) will let you provide a filename for the generated image. If you updated your templates to process the images with CE Image, I imagine you could pass in a field value for that, either bundling fields that exist in the entry or Matrix columns or a specific filename field.

If you're going for SEO, I'm not sure how you would automatically rename them without having source data to generate the new names.

Comment: Re: automatically: I was thinking of naming them based on the entry title + descriptive caption, but yes, we could certainly add another field to the Matrix for this.

Comment: Yeah, the concern there would be spaces and strange characters in either of those fields. Sounds like this will do the trick, though.

Comment: Low replace is something you can use to make sure those pesky special characters are removed http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace/docs

Comment: I like this solution. It would be better if the additional info at the end of the image (quality, resize etc) wasn't added, since it makes the name longer (e.g. imagename.jpg vs imagename_200_74_s_c1.jpg) But it's a good simple solution. I already love CE Image.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can also rename images using Assets 2. [image]

(The muffins were delicious. ;) )