# Renaming image files upon upload.. Channel Images?

Tags: file-uploads, image, channel-images

I have a gallery on each of my single entry pages, that includes image files uploaded by my users.

Is there a way to automatically change the filenames of these images upon upload? Something like `IMG1074.jpg` to `entry_title_001.jpg`?

I'm outputting the images via CE image, and I have tried the `filename=` parameter, but that renames all the images within the gallery to the same filename.

Comment: Auto renaming files on upload is a bit tricky, but not impossible. We currently are working on a new release of Channel Images, ill try to see if i can sneak that feature in.

Comment: Would love it if you could work that in!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's something unique per-image [in the Channel Images output](http://www.devdemon.com/docs/channel_images/tags/images.html#variables) (assuming your gallery is just a dump of all images assigned to the field), you should be able to append that unique value to your `entry_title`, right?

```
filename="{url_title}_{image:id}"
```

It's not something I've done, but I'm assuming you can do more with the `filename` parameter to make those filenames unique.

I think this solution was successfully applied in this question: [Renaming image file names](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5875/293).

Comment: You're right. I totally forgot the values of channel images. image:id has worked for the output. Still would be nice to have the originals renamed, but will suffice for now.